# How do you marshall XMLGregorianCalender with JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have tried to write out the XML version of an XMLGregorianCalender usign JAXB to create an XML Web Services request. But it will not print it out.

```
    private static XMLGregorianCalendar getXmlDate() throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
        return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date()));
    }
```

Elsewhere in the same class

```
   try {
        applicationHeader.setApplicationDate(getXmlDate());
    } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So it calls the generated code in the ApplicationHeader class...

```
    @XmlElement(name = "ApplicationDate", required = true)
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar applicationDate;

    public XMLGregorianCalendar getApplicationDate() {
        return applicationDate;
    }

    public void setApplicationDate(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
        this.applicationDate = value;
    }
    ...
```

So I expected to get something like

```
    <ApplicationDate>2009-03-13</ApplicationDate>
```

but I got

```
    <ApplicationDate></ApplicationDate>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Try this JAXB.marshal(obj, System.out); it prints XMLGregorianCalendar  for me

Answer (score 4):

Apparently JAXB cannot handle XMLGregorianCalender types. So I solved this through using the JAXB **XmlAdapter**, which essentially allows us to map any type of class. Where a ...

**BoundType** - a type JAXB does not knows how to handle. In this case an XMLGregorianCalender.

**ValueType** - a type that JAXB does  in fact know how to handle. In this case a type String.

So you extend the XMLAdapter to convert from a BoundType to  a ValueType when you are generating your XML request. So we are essentially creating an in-memory representation of the type in the ValueType.

So the code looks as follows,

```
public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, XMLGregorianCalendar>  {

    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    // Unmarshal by converting the value type to a bound type.
    @Override
    public XMLGregorianCalendar unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(v);
    }

    // Marshal by converting the bound type to a value type.
    @Override
    public String marshal(XMLGregorianCalendar v) throws Exception {
        synchronized (dateFormat) {
            //return dateFormat.format(v);
            return specialFormatForXmlGregorianCalander(v);
        }
    }

    // Because you cannot format an XMLGregorianCalender typyou need to generate a GregorianCalender from it first  
    private String specialFormatForXmlGregorianCalander(XMLGregorianCalendar calander){
        // Convert from XMLGregorianCalander to GregorianCalander
        GregorianCalendar gCalender = calander.toGregorianCalendar();

        // Get the date
        java.util.Date date = gCalender.getTime();

        //define the type of calendar to be GegorianCalander
        dateFormat.setCalendar(gCalender);

        // Return the string version
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
}
```

So now in my JAXB Generated class ApplicatioHeader, I need to annotate in order to tell JAXB to use the XMLAdaptor called DateAdaptor.

```
    @XmlElement(name = "ApplicationDate", required = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar applicationDate;
```

On re-running my code I got

```
    <app1:ApplicationDate>2017-08-15</app1:ApplicationDate>
```